# Why did Python 3 changes to exec break this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, exec, backwards-compatibility

I looked through the myriad 'Python exec' threads on SO, but couldn't find one that answered my issue. Terribly sorry if this has been asked before. Here's my problem:

```
# Python 2.6: prints 'it is working'
# Python 3.1.2: "NameError: global name 'a_func' is not defined"
class Testing(object):
  def __init__(self):
    exec("""def a_func():
      print('it is working')""")
    a_func()

Testing()
```

---

```
# Python 2.6: prints 'it is working'
# Python 3.1.2: prints 'it is working'
class Testing(object):
  def __init__(self):
    def a_func():
      print('it is working')
    a_func()

Testing()
```

As the standard function definition works in both Python versions, I'm assuming the problem must be a change to the way exec works. I read the API docs for 2.6 and 3 for `exec` and also read the "What's New In Python 3.0" page and couldn't see any reason why the code would break.

Comment: That seems like code that is highly likely to make whoever has to maintain it in 5 years cry.

Comment: I think this is more of a contained example than actual use of code. I hear `exec` and `eval` have their places in the language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see the generated bytecode for each Python version with:

```
>>> from dis import dis
```

And, for each interpreter:

```
#Python 3.2
>>> dis(Testing.__init__)
...
  5          10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (a_func)
...

#Python 2.7
>>> dis(Testing.__init__)
...
  5           8 LOAD_NAME                0 (a_func)
...
```

As you can see, Python 3.2 searches for a global value (LOAD_GLOBAL) named `a_func` and 2.7 first searches the local scope (LOAD_NAME) before searching the global one.

If you do `print(locals())` after the `exec`, you'll see that `a_func` is created inside the `__init__` function.

I don't really know why it's done that way, but seems to be a change on how [symbol tables](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/18/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-1/) are processed.

BTW, if want to create a `a_func = None` on top of your `__init__` method to make the interpreter know it's a local variable, it'll not work since the bytecode now will be `LOAD_FAST` and that don't make a search but directly gets the value from a list.

The only solution I see is to add `globals()` as second argument to `exec`, so that will create `a_func` as a global function an may be accessed by the `LOAD_GLOBAL` opcode.

**Edit**

If you remove the `exec` statement, Python2.7 change the bytecode from `LOAD_NAME` to `LOAD_GLOBAL`. So, using `exec`, your code will always be slower on Python2.x because it has to search the local scope for changes.

As Python3's `exec` is not a keyword, the interpreter can't be sure if it's really executing new code or doing something else... So the bytecode don't change.

E.g.

```
>>> exec = len
>>> exec([1,2,3])
3
```

---

**tl;dr**

`exec('...', globals())` may solve the problem if you don't care the result being added to global namespace

Comment: It worked. Great answer; the bytecode introspection is really cool. Didn't know about that. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: As `exec` is considering the local scope, and as `locals()` stores it, one can also do `exec("a_func()")` or `locals()['a_func']()`.

Comment: So the basic jist is that in 2.7 python is doing some hackery to notice such things as `exec` is a built-in, but now `exec` is "just another function", such hackery has been removed?

Comment: @MGGwynne: "...such hackery has been removed". I see. I'm fairly new to Python, but I've done some reading over the past couple days and read [the doc](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) covering the philosophy behind Python 3 (i.e. breaking backwards compatibility to remove warts), so this change makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Completing the answer above, just in case.  If the `exec` is in some function, I would recommend using the three-argument version as follows:

```
def f():
    d = {}
    exec("def myfunc(): ...", globals(), d)
    d["myfunc"]()
```

This is the cleanest solution, as it doesn't modify any namespace under your feet.  Instead, `myfunc` is stored in the explicit dictionary `d`.

Comment: I like this, feels safer to me :)