# Variables declared in exec'ed code don't become local in Python 3 – documentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code

```
x = 3
def f():
    exec("x = 2")
    print(x)
f()
```

runs on both Python 2 and Python 3, but prints different results.  Is this change documented anywhere?  (A pointer to a mailing list discussion would also be fine -- I ask this purely out of curiosity.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because some hackery were removed from Python 3.

The new documentation about the [`exec()` function](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#exec) has some Notes about that but don't fully explain the situtation.

Python 2, after seeing a `exec` statement, change every access to vars and functions to LOAD_NAME instead of LOAD_FAST or LOAD_GLOBAL.

Check my other answer about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561482/why-did-python-3-changes-to-exec-break-this-code/6561705#6561705).

Comment: I'm well aware of this -- it doesn't answer my question, though.  Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Oh, you're talking about documentation... I never saw it documented but it should be somewhere

Comment: That's probably the best documentation pointer I'll get, so I accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue6862) in the bug tracker -- not exactly documentation, though.

Ah, and [this one](http://bugs.python.org/issue4831) is even better!

Okay, possibly [the best one](http://bugs.python.org/issue4447) yet.