# Using a function defined in an exec'ed string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

Why does the following python3 code produces an error?

```py
a='''
def x():
  print(42)
'''

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        exec(a)
        x()

t = Test()
```

Results in this message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bug.py", line 11, in <module>
    t = Test()
  File "bug.py", line 9, in __init__
    x()
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: `eval()` or `exec()`? Question title and the code are at odds with each other.

Comment: Another interesting question: what are you trying to accomplish with exec, and what's the more-natural Python way to do it?

Comment: Loads of precedent to answer your question; [Why did Python 3 changes to exec break this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6561482) for example, or [Behaviour of exec function in Python 2 and Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15086040) or [How does exec work with locals?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1463306)

Answer (score 28):

Note: `exec` was just a Simple statement in Python 2.x, whereas it is a function in Python 3.x.

#### Python 2.7

Let us check the changes made by executing `a`.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        l, g = locals().copy(), globals().copy()
        exec a           # NOT a function call but a statement
        print locals() == l, globals() == g
        x()

t = Test()
```

**Output**

```
False True
42
```

It means that, it has changed something in the `locals` dictionary. If you print `locals().keys()` before and after the `exec`, you will see `x`, after `exec`. As per the documentation of [exec](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec),

> In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the current scope.

So, it does exactly what the documentation says.

#### Python 3.x:

When we execute the same in Python 3.x, we get similar result, except we get that error.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        l, g = locals().copy(), globals().copy()
        exec(a)          # Function call, NOT a statement
        print(locals() == l, globals() == g)
        x()
```

**Output**

```
False True
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Even the [documentation of `exec` function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#exec) says,

> In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the current scope.

But it also includes a note at the bottom,

> **Note:** The default locals act as described for function `locals()` below: **modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted**. Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function `exec()` returns.

So, we curiously check the [`locals()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#locals) and find

> **Note:** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

So, interpreter doesn't honor the changes made to the `locals()` object. That is why it is not recognizing `x` as defined in the local scope.

But when we do

```
def __init__(self):
    exec(a, globals())
    x()
```

it works, because we add it to the `globals` dictionary. Python tries to find `x` in local scope first and then in class scope and then in global scope and it finds it there. So it executes it without any problem.

Comment: **Excellent commentary.** In my case, "Pass an explicit `locals` dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function `exec()` returns." was _exactly_ the obscure solution I was uselessly grepping about for. I grep no longer. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Python3 [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#exec) also takes `globals` and `locals` optional arguments of mapping type, which act as a context for the given code execution:

```
exec(object[, globals[, locals]])
```

By default the local scope gets passed in for both. The executed code can use it, can also modify the dict, but it will have no effect on the actual local scope. See [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#locals) and example:

```
a = '''
print(t)

def x():
    print(42)
'''

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        t = 'locals are accessible'
        # same as calling exec(a, locals())
        exec(a)
        print(locals())
        x()

t = Test()
```

Output:

```
locals are accessible
{'x': <function x at 0x6ffffd09af0>,
'self': <__main__.Test object at 0x6ffffce3f90>,
't': 'locals are accessible'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in __init__
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

If you want the `x` to be available after the `exec` call you either need to pass in a global or a custom scope:

```
# global scope
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        exec(a, globals())
        x()

# custom scope
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        scope = {}
        exec(a, scope)
        scope['x']()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was needed!
A way to save locally the function from the `string` code and call it in the local scope without effect the global scope of the program. Excellent :)

Comment: Same, this is exactly what I need, Thank you!

Comment: Hi @amousgarkin, where did you know this "By default the local scope gets passed in for both." ? There's no default value shown in the `exec ` function signature

Answer (score 14):

I am assuming you are using Python3.x, since in Python2.7, your code is working fine for me.
So for Python3.x, change the line

```
exec(a)
```

to

```
exec(a, globals())
```

in order to add `x` to the global namespace.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#exec)

Comment: In Python 2, `exec` is a *statement*, not a function. The compiler disables the local namespace optimisation when you use `exec`, which is why it works there. Python 3 no longer does this.