# Django shell script definition error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, shell

I have a file `test.py` with this code:

```
def getTrue():
    return True

def getSome():
    return getTrue()

somevar = getSome()
print(somevar)
```

When I run the script using

```
python manage.py shell < test.py
```

I get the error

```
NameError: name 'getTrue' is not defined
```

After adding

```
import unicodedata
```

To the top of the file and then try using some function from unicodedata I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'unicodedata' is not defined
```

I don't see how the answer to the question that my question is marked as a possible duplicate of is answering this part.

When I run the file normally with

```
python3 /path/to/file/test.py
```

There is no problem and `True` is printed like expected.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: When you do this, the script internally calls `exec()` on the code in `test.py`. This will fail in Python 3 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733831/using-a-function-defined-in-an-execed-string-in-python-3) for a detailed explanation of why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a function defined in an exec'ed string in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733831/using-a-function-defined-in-an-execed-string-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

Piping a script into a Django shell is like copying & pasting it into the shell. The "smart" auto-indentation logic of the shell often gets confused and over-ident the pasted code.

Try installing the latest iPython, which has this issue resolved. Django will use iPython as the shell if it's installed.