# Python3 dynamic import with exec - why does 'as' not be executed?

Tags: python, import, module, exec

I have this code that carry module manually

```
exec("import" + moduleName + " as selectedModule")
importlib.reload(selectedModule)
```

But this code make

```
name 'seletedModule' is not defined
```

It is not happened on python2.x.
How to import this on python3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to import a library dynamically, don't use `exec`, **its not safe**.

Use `importlib.import_module` instead.

```
selected_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
importlib.reload(selected_module)
```

---

As for the error you're getting: you're probably calling `exec` within a function scope, thus you'll need you manually set `globals` and `locals` to be the same in `exec` ([Using a function defined in an exec'ed string in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24733831/6622817)). Workaround:

```
exec("<do-stuff>", globals())
```