# Python define function within function

Tags: python, function

I would like to define a function within a function, and call it from out of the function. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
def make_func():
    exec('def test(text):\n\tprint(text)')


make_func()
test("Hello")
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 6, in <module>
    test("Hello")
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: why would you want to do that? i think test is defined only in the scope of the exec

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for another function I can use?

Comment: What's the point? What purpose are you trying to achieve, that you couldn't achieve by defining functions the normal way? (And why did you bring `exec` into this?)

Comment: This is a simplified version of my actual code, in which I have to dynamically create a function from within a function. I don't NEED to use `exec()`, but I can't think of another way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test` function is defined inside the `make_func` function and thus is local to it, to make it global (reachable from anywhere in the code) use (for Python 2.7):

```
def make_func():
    exec('def test(text):\n\tprint(text)')
    globals()['test'] = test

make_func()
test("Hello")  #  ==>  Hello
```

For Python 3.x:

```
def make_func():
    exec('def test(text):\n\tprint(text)', globals())

make_func()
test("Hello")  #  ==>  Hello
```

Comment: I just get this error: `line 3, in make_func
    globals()['test'] = test
NameError: name 'test' is not defined`

Comment: @Pokechu48 It works with Python 2.7, I'll see a workaround with Python 3.x.

Comment: @Pokechu48 Check the edit for a workaround for Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

**Revision:**

You need to add test to the global namescape.  Here is the solution:

```
def make_func():
    exec('def test(text):\n\tprint(text)', globals())


make_func()
test("Hello")
```

**NOTE:**
This has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733831/using-a-function-defined-in-an-execed-string-in-python-3).

---

**Previous:**

See [Python exec()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-in-python/).  You cannot call text("Hello) because text() has fallen out-of-scope and is no longer defined.  It's only defined within the scope of exec().

However, you could do this:

```
def make_func():
    exec('def test(text):\n\tprint(text)\ntest("Hello")')


make_func()
```

Or:

```
def make_func(text):
    exec('def test(text):\n\tprint(text)\ntest(text)')


make_func("Hello")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am looking to call the function from outside the `exec()` statement, but thank you for this suggestion

Comment: I am saying, that is not possible.  Functions defined within exec() are only available within the scope of exec().  See link.

Comment: Is there another function I can use instead of `exec()`?

Comment: I cannot imagine there is, but I do not know.  I think it's unlikely.

Comment: This isn't right. Names defined inside an exec can be used outside it.

Comment: Please provide evidence.

Comment: ["the code is executed in the current scope"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

Comment: `exec('test = "Hello"')` would create a variable called `test` with the value of `"Hello"`. The command `print(test)` prints `"Hello"`, even though the `print()` function is outside of the `exec()`

Comment: I added a revision.  You can use the function, but you need to explicitly change the scope.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I was unaware of what to search for, which could explain the duplicate question