# Python 3 exec method : NameError: name of a defined function is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, exec, dynamic-programming

### worker file: vir.py

```
def calcCycleOffset():
    global cycleOffset, uc, cs

    cycleOffset = uc - cs
    return cycleOffset


def vir_main():
    calcCycleOffset()


vir_main()
#calcCycleOffset()


print( "vir.py: cycleOffset: ", cycleOffset )
```

### executor file: exec.py

```
filename = "./vir.py"
vir_globals = { "uc": 42, "cs": 12, "cycleOffset": -1 }

with open(filename, "rb") as source_file:
    code = compile(source_file.read(), filename, "exec")

exec(code, vir_globals, {} )

print( 'exec: globals.cycleOffset', vir_globals['cycleOffset'] )
```

this pattern fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exec.py", line 7, in <module>
    exec(code, vir_globals, {} )
  File "./vir.py", line 12, in <module>
    vir_main()
  File "./vir.py", line 9, in vir_main
    calcCycleOffset()
NameError: name 'calcCycleOffset' is not defined
```

however, the function calcCycleOffset() is known to python. if you switch commenting in vir.py from:

```
vir_main()
#calcCycleOffset()
```

to:

```
#vir_main()
calcCycleOffset()
```

then the function is called OK.

I would like to be able to nest functions within function in the vir.py file and still be able to execute it dynamically...

HELP !

thanks

Comment: I think that there is a scope problem here....did you check your locals() ?

Comment: I checked the locals, they hold the function correctly... HELP !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained here in official documentation about the **locals** object: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#locals

> **Note** : The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes
>   may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the
>   interpreter.

And You passed here an empty object as locals.

In your executor files Please change your code to :

```
filename = "./vir.py"
vir_globals = { "uc": 42, "cs": 12, "cycleOffset": -1 }

with open(filename, "rb") as source_file:
    code = compile(source_file.read(), filename, "exec")

exec(code, vir_globals) #remove the empty object here !!

print( 'exec: globals.cycleOffset', vir_globals['cycleOffset'] )
```

and it should to the tricks

You can also take a look at this question and excellent answer from @thefourtheye
[Using a function defined in an exec'ed string in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733831/using-a-function-defined-in-an-execed-string-in-python-3)