# Why use exec to create function dynamically inside a class method doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I learnt that `exec` can create function dynamically from this post [Python: dynamically create function at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291242/python-dynamically-create-function-at-runtime) .

I want to create a function on the fly inside an instance method, and use the function after that.

But the code below fails, why?

```
class A:
    def method_a(self, input_function_str: str):
        exec('''def hello():
            print('123')
        ''')
        
        # hello() # call hello() here leads to NameError


b = A() 
b.method_a()
# hello() # call hello() here also leads to NameError
```

My goal is that I dynamically create a function based on `input_function_str` passing from outside, then use that function somewhere in `method_a`.

Comment: `exec()` can take things from current scope, but cant add things into the scope, so the `hello` function gets lost afterwards. Anyway, I wouldnt recommend doing it, seems quite unsafe. What is the use case for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a function defined in an exec'ed string in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733831/using-a-function-defined-in-an-execed-string-in-python-3)

Comment: _Please note that without sandboxing and other precautions this opens a massive security hole because the input string can contain malicious code._ See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions defined dynamically inside other functions using `exec` aren't saved to that functions `locals()`. If you save it to the `globals()` scope instead, your code will work, but you would then also be able to call `hello()` outside of your function scope

```py
def method_a(input_function_str: str = None):
    exec('''def hello():  print('123') ''', globals())
    print('inside scope:')
    hello()

method_a()
print('outside scope:')
hello()
```

See this answer for more information: [Using a function defined in an exec'ed string in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733831/using-a-function-defined-in-an-execed-string-in-python-3)