# How to use sklearn random forest model with numpy only (without sklearn) for prediction?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a trained Random Forest Regression model using sklearn. However, I need to use the model (i.e. make predictions on new data) in an environment without sklearn. I can use numpy. Basically I need to convert the sklearn model to a python structure and apply it one new data. I don't know how to do this.

Since random forest consists of trees, I tried getting the individual trees using model.estimators_. I think the next step would be to convert the tree itself to a python structure that can be used to make prediction on new data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224526/how-to-extract-the-decision-rules-from-scikit-learn-decision-tree

Comment: @NickODell, Unfortunately, this is different from what I need, it extracts the rules of a tree to text. My aim is to convert the RF regression trees to structures that can be used to predict Y-var for new data using numpy only.

Comment: @OmarAl-Attraqchi that link is what you need. If it outputs it as a string you can just copy/paste it? Otherwise you can look at using exec() ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733831/using-a-function-defined-in-an-execed-string-in-python-3)).