# How to directly refer to the exec compiled function in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

I used to create a exec statement to generate a function to use in Python2. However, when I move to Python3, the same approach stopped work ing.

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def a():
...   exec(compile("def printt(): print(2)","printt","exec"))
...   printt()
... 
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in a
NameError: name 'printt' is not defined
>>>
```

---

```
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def a():
...   exec(compile("def printt(): print(2)","printt","exec"))
...   printt()
... 
>>> a()
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, the `exec` function is no longer able to modify the local scope directly.

This is documented in [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), see the note which says:

> **Note:** The default *locals* act as described for function [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) below: modifications to the default *locals* dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit *locals* dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function `exec()` returns.

Also note that the Python 2 code is using the [`exec` statement](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html), even though you wrote it to look like a function, it's a completely different form. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15087355/9447571) for a more in-depth discussion, or even [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6561705/9447571) which covers this issue from a Python code disassembly point of view.

So, if you want to access the symbols defined in the scope of the `exec()`, you should pass it a dict (possibly empty, or pre-populated with any variable assignments or function definitions you want to use in your `exec()` block) and access it afterwards.

This code [works](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFRQ9OKS0FBIS8xN7W4IDE5VcFWoboWJJJakZqskZyfW5CZk6qhBFJbUJSZV1IC1ABhaRhpKukoQQSBDJB6JU0dkFYwSM/JT0rMKdbQ1EEYrgmShegA2gMXjlaHiKnHIuQ1NLm4gI77/x8A) in Python 3:

```
def a():
   namespace = {}
   exec(compile("def printt(): print(2)","printt","exec"),
        globals(), namespace)
   printt = namespace['printt']
   printt()
```

Hopefully this should be good enough for your purposes.